# ViewModel with Application context and extra parameter in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-architecture

We knew that in order to access `Application` context like need to find a resource string or system service we extend our ViewModel with `AndroidViewModel` while passing extra arguments to a ViewModel requires a factory that extend `ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()`. My question is when you are using `AndroidViewModel` you don't need to pass `Application` as a parameter in constructing your ViewModel but when using a factory you will need to pass Application context along with your extra argument.

Is getActivity().getApplication() being done internally when just using `AndroidViewModel`?
Is it okay to explicitly pass `getActivity().getApplication()` in Fragment to your ViewModel factory?

Sample

ViewModel that only needs Application context

```
class AssetViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

}
```

The above ViewModel can be construct in Fragment just like the default way.

```
val assetViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AssetViewModel::class.java)
```

However with a factory you will be doing it like this

```
class NewsVideoViewModelFactory(private val application: Application, private val baseUrl: String) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return NewsVideoViewModel(application, baseUrl) as T
    }

}

class NewsVideoViewModel(application: Application, baseUrl: String) : AndroidViewModel(application){

   

}
```

Then construct it like this and relying on Activity

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, NewsVideoViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application, baseUrl)).get(
            NewsVideoViewModel::class.java)
```

Is this correct and not against the concept or best practice in using ViewModel?

Comment: Don't call `getActivity` from a ViewModel, as it is not guaranteed that an Activity is alive.

Answer (score 0):

In java, when you create a ViewModel through `AndroidViewModel`, you have to pass the Application parameter, so for the question:

> Is getActivity().getApplication() being done internally when just
> using AndroidViewModel?

You have explicitly passed the Application context to the `AndroidViewModel`. In that class there is a method `getApplication()` to receive the argument that passed. The second one:

> Is it okay to explicitly pass getActivity().getApplication() in
> Fragment to your ViewModel factory?

It is absolutely fine

Comment: What does Java have to do with this?  It is using Kotlin.